# Azure ResourceGraph Python AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, azure

I am trying to use python lib *azure.mgmt.resourcegraph* to receive list all cosmosdb accounts in my tenant.

Here is code:

```
from azure.mgmt.subscription import SubscriptionClient
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resourcegraph import ResourceGraphClient

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id, secret, tenant=tenant_id)
rgraph_object = ResourceGraphClient(credentials)

test = rgraph_object.resources(query="resources | where type == 'microsoft.documentdb/databaseaccounts'")
```

**Error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'**

Could anybody help with that?

Answer (score 1):

this:

```
"resources | where type == 'microsoft.documentdb/databaseaccounts""
```

should be this:

```
"resources | where type == 'microsoft.documentdb/databaseaccounts'"
```

Comment: Hello 4c74356b41, thanks for typo - it was my error here. It's not reason of error in general

Answer (score 1):

Well, I founded the reason.
In general - method **resources** uses specific type "[QueryRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resourcegraph/azure.mgmt.resourcegraph.models.queryrequest?view=azure-python)"

So, correct code is:

```
from azure.mgmt.subscription import SubscriptionClient
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.resourcegraph import ResourceGraphClient
from azure.mgmt.resourcegraph.models import QueryRequest

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(client_id, secret, tenant=tenant_id)
sub_object = SubscriptionClient(credentials)
rgraph_object = ResourceGraphClient(credentials)

subs = [sub.as_dict() for sub in sub_object.subscriptions.list()]

subs_list = []

for sub in subs:
    subs_list.append(sub.get('subscription_id'))

request = QueryRequest(subscriptions=subs_list, query="resources | where type == 'microsoft.documentdb/databaseaccounts'")

test = rgraph_object.resources(request)
```